# Rendering image on a transparent circle and cropping it

Tags: php, jquery, imagick

I have a background image:
[image],

on which i fuse a circle(or eclipse):
[image]

so that the area equal to circle becomes transparent on the background image just like this:
 [image].

I have used php and image magick to achieve this

Now, I have to insert an image into the hole in such a way that:

1. Image is rendered above the background, so only image area equal 
   to photo hole is visible.
2. When I drag the image in photo hole, the    image goes in layer behind background and when released again the image is re-rendered as step 1.
3. I also need to crop the image rendered in step 1.

How this can be achieved in php using image magick? Any pointers or help will very useful.

To transfer image below the background on layer, can this be done using z-index?

Comment: Your question is very confusing (or very confused). If you want the image to be dragged/change z-index, you'll have to do this with javascript. Once the object is dropped, you'll then pass the necessary info back to the server (`posX`,`posX`,`above_or_below`) and have imageMagick render accordingly.

Comment: yes, but my question is how do i make the part of image(only) that's visible though transparent hole rendered above the background?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the above, I took this appraoch:

1. I place a image in a div (exactly surrounding the circle) which is behind the background image. The div has overflow hidden, so I can contain image.
2. In order to drag image I transfer mouse down event on background image to the below div. This can be done using jQuery trigger.
3. Now to crop the image I calculate the x,y offset of images and crop height and width accordingly and send data to server to crop it.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Cropping the image to the same dimensions as the circle and then place it on top of the background image at position posX,posY etc could work as a nice straight forward solution.

Comment: i need to have that image draggable also, so user can drag it and change. I hope you understand my requirement.  When i drag the image in photo hole, the image goes in layer behind background and when released again the image is re-rendered on top. I f i crop it before, how the user will be bale to drag then?